# Python PyQt5: Store image data into a phpmyadmin database

Tags: python, sql, database, image, pyqt5

I want to upload a .png file into my database.

```
    fileName = QFileDialog().getOpenFileName()
    filePath = str(fileName[0]) # Path of the image data

    self.myImage = filePath


    connection = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    db = 'mydatabase',
    cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)  
    cur = connection.cursor()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('" + self.myImage + "')")  
    connection.commit()
```

But something is wrong, because if I look in my local database the image is saved as binary file and I can't open or download it. 
What can I do to upload an image into my database properly?

Comment: An image file is nothing but bytes - just like any other file. Why can't you open or download it? What have you tried? What *specifically* went wrong? The code in your question does not upload a file; it just inserts a file-path into the database.

Comment: Yes, this is why it doesn't work. If I want to download the "wrong path file", it comes out a small binary file and not an image file. You can't open it and it's useless. I want to upload a file and not the path. I thought the path refers to the file, but it doesn't. What must I do to upload the image file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to read the image file and store the data as a blob in the database:

```
with open(filePath, 'rb') as stream:
    blob = stream.read()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(%s)", [blob])
```

To convert the blob into a pixmap:

```
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
pixmap.loadFromData(blob)
```