# Python PyQt5: Cannot save JPG files into database

Tags: php, python, mysql, phpmyadmin, filesize

I already asked how to save image data into phpmyadmin database. [Python PyQt5: Store image data into a phpmyadmin database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317999/python-pyqt5-store-image-data-into-a-phpmyadmin-database)

This problem is solved, but there is another problem:
When I uploaded a jpg file (size: 6.64 MB) following error occurs:
(2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query ([WinError 10053]...)

I think the source of this problem is that the size is too big.

Should I only use images with less than 1 MB or is there a possibillity to upload jpg files with sizes of over 6 MB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to modify your my.cnf or my.ini file. The files are located at BASEDIR\my.ini and BASEDIR\my.cnf (.ini is for Windows and .cnf is for unix). In that file, find [mysqld] section and add the following line to change the maximum allowed packet:

```
max_allowed_packet=10M
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I found the my.ini file and changed under [mysqld] the max_allowed_packet into 10M. Anyway, I opened my local phpMyAdmin database and unfortunately I still can't upload longblobs with a size greater than 2.048KiB.Nothing has changed yet. Or maybe I have to use another database.

Comment: Now I receive following error occurrence: "(1118, 'The size of BLOB/TEXT data inserted in one transaction is greater than 10% of redo log size. Increase the redo log size using innodb_log_file_size.')"

Comment: @AlanHorman, it seems that you have to make another modification i.e. innodb_log_file_size. Please try to increase it by modifying the innodb_log_file_size below `[mysqld]`. You should modify from

Comment: Sorry, accidentally press enter. Try to modify like this:

    [mysqld]
    ....
    innodb_log_file_size=128

However, you should be very careful before modifying the innodb log configuration. Please shut down the server first and move the existing log files to somewhere else.